# If an event $A$ has $P(A)$=$1$, then $A^c$ is empty?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to see if the statement "if $P(A)=1, P(B)=P(B \cap A)$" is true.

My thought process was that
$P(B) = P(B \cap A)+P(B \cap A^c)$, and if $P(A)=1$, then $P(B \cap A^c) = 0$ because $A^c$ is empty, but I'm not sure if that is true. Intuitively, I believe the statement above should be true, but I'm not sure if my reasoning is okay.

Any comment or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Since $P$ is a (probability) measure, it is not true that $A = \Omega$ ($\Omega$ : sample space) even if $P(A) = 1$. Your reasoning is right **almost surely**.

Comment: If $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1$, then $\mathbb{P}(A^c) = 0$, but $A^c$ does not have to be the empty set.

Comment: Then how could I argue that $P(B)=P(B \cap A)$ since $P(B \cap A^c)=0$, or is that statement false to begin with?

Comment: It is false that $P(E)=0\implies P=\varnothing$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there.

However, as noted in the comments, it's not true that $A^c$is empty. What is true is that because $P(A)=1$, then $P(A^c)=0$.

It follows that $$P(B\cap A^c) \leq P(A^c)=0$$
Which yields the desired result.

Comment: Ah, by the monotonicity of probability measures, right?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: It's kind of frustrating to not be able to see something nearly trivial :/ thank you anyways!

Comment: No worries. I've been stuck one million times on simple stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are write because as we know P(B)=P(A intersection B) this implies that B is contained in A or B will only happen if A happen this means that B will not happen if A did not happen so P(B intersection A') is zero but also we know A is sure event this means P(A')=1-P(A)=0 .But this does not means that A is an empty set.